# Hiding elements in swift using segmented controls

Tags: swift, label, hide, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to hide specific labels in my view with a segmented control. In case 0 I only want to display certain labels # 1/2/5, and in case two I want to display labels # 2/4/5.

But something is wrong.... Nothing happens when I select the second segment, and all my content gets hidden after then pressing the first segment.

Am I on the right path, or should I use something conditional? (label"A" is hidden if segment 0 or something)

````
    @IBAction func DriveTypeChange(_ sender: Any) {
            if DriveTypeControler.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                InVenueDriveMaxLoad.isHidden = true
            }
            if DriveTypeControler.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
                InVenueDriveMaxLoad.isHidden = false
        }
    ```

    }
````

Comment: Is this method for UIsegmentcontroller value change ??

Comment: No, I'm trying to use the segmentcontroller to hide my labels, or didn't I get the question?

Comment: you should share your all code because your implementation, naming, action block not good implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create `@IBAction` for `valueChanged` action of `UISegmentedControl`.

Now, as per your requirement to hide/show `labels` based on `selectedSegmentIndex`,

```
@IBAction func driveTypeChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    label1.isHidden = (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    label2.isHidden = false
    label4.isHidden = (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    label5.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Thread 1: Exception: "-[LoadFlyer.ViewController DriveTypeChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fda9b017800"

Comment: I created a new ibaction, but now I get: 

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: What are you unwrapping?

Comment: Good question, The labels in question are double()-type outputs, but changing the hidden state doesn't involve any unwrapping does it? And the labels I'm trying to hide/view are empty as of now. Only a default text "...kg" As they are witing for that function to be implemented.
Or is that the whole problem? That I'm trying to hide an empty label?

Comment: Are the labels connected properly in the storyboard? And what do you mean by double type? labels must be of type UILabel.

Comment: I Maybe, might, possibly have gone a bit too fast here ;-) After reconnecting (correctly this time) the labels verything is working as you said!! Thanks a million!